# Can I use per unit method for true, reactive, and apparent Power

Tags: electrical

I would like to show apparent power (S) in Cartesian coordinate system with a circle of radius 1, where x axis represents reactive power (Q), and y axis represents true power (P). There's the formula:

```
P^2+Q^2=S^2
```

Can I use these formulas to transform it in per unit system:

```
P[p.u.] = P / S
Q[p.u.] = Q / S
S[p.u.] = S / S = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your formulas are correct.

(P, Q) is a vector in your coordinate system. S is the length of this vector. By dividing the components of the vector by its length, you normalize it, creating an unit vector that's pointing in the same direction.

Then you can draw this unit vector into your coordinate system.